# DIV positioning (multiple divs, different Z index)

Tags: css

This question has been posted multiple times but I cannot find one discussion that would help me to find a solution yet.
How can I get rid of this extra space at the bottom, after the `#AnotherDiv` has moved?
I tried other setups as well, like use an outer div (width 100%) and place the `#content` and `#AnotherDiv` inside, but then the `#AnotherDiv` doesn't stay at the bottom at all (I used `position` `absolute` and `bottom` 0). All I want is to have the `#AnotherDiv` aligned at the bottom of the footer div.

http://jsfiddle.net/bW7h2/10/

```
#AnotherDiv {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Comment: I think you want to set `bottom` to `0px` (or just remove it), no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `margin-top: -200px;` instead of `bottom:200px;` for your `#AnotherDiv` element.
And you were missing an `;` in your CSS:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bW7h2/12/)**</kbd>

```
#homepage{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}
/* Header, Body, Footer */
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    z-index: 1;        /* 1 IS QUITE ENOUGH, SET '0' FOR #AnotherDiv */
}

#data {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
}
#footer {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;  /* MISSING ; */
    position: relative;
    background-color: gold;
}

#AnotherDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: -200px;  /* INSTEAD OF bottom:200px; */
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your comment is you want to do this?

```
#AnotherDiv {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Comment: Not fixed, i don't want it to appear the entire time on the screen. It should automatically move with the content height.